# PHP | Security for allowing user uploads

Tags: php, security, iis, file-upload, download

**My Sittuation:**

I am creating a web application with **PHP** which allows users to scan their files for viruses. It allows the user to upload their files via the html "file" input type or via a URL. I have successfully built the html and PHP side of things and users are able to successfully upload files onto my server. I am using windows server 2012 R2 with IIS as my webserver

**My Question:**

As far as I am aware, There is little to no security in place (both script and server side) to avoid security/attack vulnerabilities on my website or yet worse, on the server its self. I am aware that attackers could potentially upload and executed files that can hack my server. **So, What steps can I take to try and eliminate these issues**.

**Things I Am Aware Of:**

Due to the research I conducted, it is to my understanding that I could potentially do the following to strengthen my self, however these are all theories, and I have no idea how to actually put them in place (hence why I am asking):

- Restriction on file types (Yes I could potentially block .php files, but as an example - I cannot block common .exe's as the user would most likely scan a executable) *What is the correct balance for this sort of service, as limiting too many file types just removes usability*
- Storing uploaded files in a different drive - My site directory is in the C drive and I have an empty D drive I could use. *How do I disable the server from executing anything in the specific drive? How do I stop Hackers from navigating to that drive and executing the uploaded files?*

**Things I have Tried:**

- I have Created a function to rename the file uploaded to a md5 hash of it, with a unique ID at the beginning, so therefore the user cannot identify the file easily.
- Limited file type to remove .php uploads? Perhaps there are others which would be valid for my purpose?

**Conclusion:**

So essentially, as well as answers to the minor questions above. I am looking for a list of actions I can take to strenghten the application and server, to eliminate any possible threats. Thanks

**Code:**

As a side note, below you can see my code. Just in case you spot anything serious in there. Or there are extra security which can be added to the code:

PHP:

```
$upload_directory = "uploads/";
    $uploaded_file = $upload_directory . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $upload_ok = 1;

    $image_file_type = pathinfo($uploaded_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // check for files bigger then 8mb
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 8388608){
        print "your file exceeds 8mb";
        $upload_ok = 0;
        exit();
    }

    // only allow certain file types
    if($image_file_type != "jpg" && $image_file_type != "png" && $image_file_type != "jpeg" && $image_file_type != "gif"){
        print "invalid file type";
        $upload_ok = 0;
        exit();
    }

    // upload it
    if($upload_ok != 0){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploaded_file);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label>Select Desired File</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Scan File"> 
</form>
```

Regards

Comment: [Same question on Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/82156/539)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly ensure that the files cannot be executed, so read-only / disable script execution and ensure they cannot be accessed via the web.

Make sure the uploaded files are not special files which may modify how you system responds eg web.config / .htaccess

Rename all uploads do not trust the original name, or accept any parameters which may allow an uploader to modify the save path.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you need to copy the files over to the upload directory? I'm not sure how it's done with Windows servers, but on a linux server files that are uploaded are copied to a temporary directory outside of the web root.

You could still open up the file by accessing $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], and perform any heuristics on that.  This would be safer than moving the file to a publicly accessible directory in the web root.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I was referring to actually downloading the file to a different directory, such as a directory outside the webroot, or better yet to a different drive?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploaded_file);`

copies the file to the upload directory in the web root.  You could instead just use $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] and work on that, rather than moving it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to be aware that its a high risk to allow virus samples on your server. Always consider they can break out.

So first of all, my recommendation would be to perform the actual analysis on a virtual machine on the server. I am aware that this is most likely not possible, still it would be the best option. Be careful to save customer data or productive stuff on a server who handles with infected executables.

After that:

- Use the MIME Type to check for the filetype, not the file extension. While this can also be faked, you have to edit the binary in a hexeditor e.g.. You can use for that: [finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). You can also check for both ofc.
- To increase security, do not allow to access uploaded files directly. If you want to allow such a feature, rather make it possible using a PHP Handler which prints the files with the [content-disposition](https://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml) flag set. That way they are not able to execute actual PHP Files on the server, so you are set up against PHP Shells.
- Limit the Write/Read Access from the Webserver User, I am not Windows Admin, so I cannot give actual hints on that one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Checking the MIME type is useless as the server decides how to handle a file solely based on the file extension.

Comment: While that is true, there are exploits where you can override that behavior. I can look for sources if you are interested, its not the first time that happened.

Comment: While I have to admit, that I couldn't find the source I had in mind right now, some further clarification: You could upload a javascript file and force it to be interpreted as JS, even with a different extension. This would make CORS quite senseless, ofc this has to be combined with a XSS Vulnerability, but yet combined its quite powerful. The same works when there is some application which sends manually content headers. Why blacklists with extensions are bad can be read on further here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload Its in general just considered insecure.